# Anti-forgery cookie issues after a deployment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I keep getting the below error after deploying my ASP.NET MVC project to Azure Web Sites

```
A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid.
```

This seems like it only happens with the following steps:

1. Open browser and navigate to site's login page (this page may need to stay open for some amount of time) - **UPDATE:** This does not appear to be needed
2. Deploy project
3. Try to login
4. Get error

I do have the machine key specified

```
<machineKey validationKey="[vKey]" decryptionKey="[dKey]" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

so I thought that should protect me from this happening. Any thoughts?

UPDATE: I am publishing from Visual Studio and the destination URL was set to http://[appName].azurewebsites.net instead of the custom domain that I use for FB authentication. I am on the custom domain when I actually log in so maybe there is some sort of caching issue? Not sure. As it doesn't always seem to repro, it's hard to determine if that made any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added DonutOutputCache to the ExternalLoginsList thinking I was being clever. This is a lesson in YAGNI.